# is there a way to disable a mega-detailed error message in Rundeck's failed executions?

Tags: rundeck

The message that is posted every time an execution fails is too verbose and creates too much noise. Is there a way to disable or hide it somehow? We have our own error messages within the scripts and don't need a red chunk of extra text displayed in the logs. Adding an error handler that will exit with code 0 is not an option because we still need the job to fail if a step fails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That message is Rundeck standard output in case of failure (you can manipulate the [loglevel](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/job-v20.html#loglevel) but that doesn't affect the NonZeroResultCode last line, just the text from your commands/scripts), you can suggest that [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues). The rest are just workarounds as you mentioned.

This [occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD5fM.jpg) even using the [Quiet output](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/quiet-output.html#quiet-output).